# Best practice to apply patch to a modified docker container?

Tags: docker, operation

So let's say we just spun up a docker container and allows user SSH into the container by mapping port `22:22`.

User then installed some software like git or whatever they want. So that container is now **polluted**.

Later on, suppose I want to apply some patches to the container, what is the best way to do so?

Keep in mind that the user has modified contents in container, including some system level directories like `/usr/bin`. So I cannot simply replace the running container with another image.

So to give you some real life use cases. Take [Nitrous.io](https://www.nitrous.io/) as an example. I saw they are using docker containers to serve as user's VM. So users can install packages like Node.js global packages. So how do they update/apply patch to containers like a pro? Similar platforms like [Codeanywhere](https://codeanywhere.net/) might work in the same way.

I tried google it but I failed. I am not 100 percent sure whether this is a duplicate though.

Answer (score 3):

> User then installed some software like git or whatever they want ... I want to apply some patch to the container, what is the best way to do so ?

The recommended way is to plan your updates through `Dockerfile`. However, if you are unable to achieve that, than any additional changes or new packages installed to the container should be committed before they are exited.

ex: Below is simple container created which does not have `vim` installed.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
pingimg             1.5                 1e29ac7353d1        4 minutes ago       209.6 MB
```

Start the container and check if `vim` is installed.

```
 $ docker run -it pingimg:1.5 /bin/bash
 root@f63accdae2ab:/#
 root@f63accdae2ab:/# vim
 bash: vim: command not found
```

Install the required packages, inside the container:

```
 root@f63accdae2ab:/# sudo apt-get update && install -y vim
```

Back on the host, commit the container with a new tag before stopping or exiting the container.

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
f63accdae2ab        pingimg:1.5         "/bin/bash"         About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       modest_lovelace 

$ docker commit f63accdae2ab pingimg:1.6
378e0359eedfe902640ff71df4395c3fe9590254c8c667ea3efb54e033f24cbe

$ docker stop f63accdae2ab 
f63accdae2ab
```

Now docker images should show to both the tags or versions of the container. Note, the updated container shows larger size.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
pingimg             1.6                 378e0359eedf        43 seconds ago      252.8 MB  
pingimg             1.5                 1e29ac7353d1        4 minutes ago       209.6 MB
```

Re-start the recently committed container, you can see that `vim` installed

```
$ docker run -it pingimg:1.6 /bin/bash
root@63dbbb8a9355:/# which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

Verify the contents of the previous version container and should notice that `vim` is still missing.

```
$ docker run -it pingimg:1.5 /bin/bash
root@99955058ea0b:/# which vim
root@99955058ea0b:/# vim
bash: vim: command not found
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So the idea is to (1) commit user's changes (2) apply your patches to the container, and commit again (3) apply new container for user. Does this sounds feasible? And while I think this works, it should be hard to apply some kernel updates, like upgrading linux distribution version

Comment: Any changes to the container are not preserved after exiting, therefore requires to be committed if you want them to persist on the next start. You don't have to worry about kernel updates within the containers, as it only includes user space apps into an isolated and secure environment, as long as the docker engine is setup on support kernel version. hope this helps!

Comment: Do we need to commit regularly? Because server may fail and we can lose user data. Not quite relevant to this question, but just curious.

Comment: Oh I just figured out that we should use data volumes for db containers.

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole branch of software called [configuration management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) that seeks to solve this issue, with solutions such as [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) and [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/). Whilst designed with VMs in mind, it is certainly possible to use such solutions with containers.

However, this is not the Docker way. Rather than patch a Docker container, throw it away and replace it with a new one. If you need to install new software, add it to the Dockerfile and build a new container as per @askb's solution. By doing things this way, we can avoid a whole set of headaches (similarly, prefer `docker exec` to installing ssh in containers).

Comment: OT: wondering if criu when it lands in docker will make it easier to move your code to a patched container?